# puppet apply and extlookup

Tags: linux, puppet

I still use extlookup (Yes, I know that it's deprecated :-( But I can't find time to move to hiera).

My problem - I need to move from puppet master/puppet agent setup, to puppet apply that is run locally. Everything was smooth... except of extlookup.

When I try to use:

```
puppet apply -e 'class { 'classX': }'
```

And if somewhere inside of **classX** (or inside of one of required classes) extlookup is used, **extlookup_datadir** is fully ignored. No matter where I'll define/declare that variable.

I tried in classX **init.pp** file above class declaration, and inside of class declaration.

So the question is - is possible to use extlookup somehow with

```
puppet apply -e
```

? :-)

Comment: The only solution that I see now, is to create sth.pp with node '...' definition, and add everything there. But this solution sucks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that came into my mind after some thinking:

```
cat<<EOF | puppet apply --noop
$(cat /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp)
node "$(hostname -f)" {
    my::definition { "resName" }
}
EOF
```

As with puppetmaster setup I put in site.pp **extlookup_datadir** and **extlookup_precedence**. So I don't need to change anything in my manifests - only to use this "wrapper".

I'll appreciate any better solutions :-)